# Importing in Python failing

Tags: python, git, import, mercurial

I am following the instructions on [this blog post](http://www.appveyor.com/blog/2014/02/23/converting-mercurial-repository-to-git-on-windows), to convert from Mercurial to Git

When I run the script as such:

```
hg-fast-export.sh -r c:\projects\demoapp
```

Then it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hg-fast-export.py", line 11, in <module>
    from mercurial import node
ImportError: cannot import name node
```

And the begining of my hg-fast-export.py looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) 2007, 2008 Rocco Rutte <pdmef@gmx.net> and others.
# License: MIT <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php>

import sys

# import mercurial libraries from zip:
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\library.zip')

from mercurial import node
from hg2git import setup_repo,fixup_user,get_branch,get_changeset
from hg2git import load_cache,save_cache,get_git_sha1,set_default_branch,set_origin_name
from optparse import OptionParser
import re
import os
```

I checked the `library.zip` file (which is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\`, and it contains the following folder structure (in addition to many other files/folders insize `library.zip`

```
library.zip
    |
    ---------mercurial
            |
            ----------node.pyc
```

I am really stumped. I do not know what to do. I have been stuck on this for two days. It maybe something very simple that I am overlooking, but I have not idea what it is. Is it a caching issue? Is it a setup issue? Is it an environment issue?

Please helpl, and thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly have *another* `mercurial` package or module in your path somewhere. Since you use `sys.path.append()` the `library.zip` file is searched **last** for the module.

Your best bet is to add library zipfile to the Python module search path at the *start*:

```
sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\library.zip')
```

Comment: Man, I do not say that to guys, but I LOVE YOU. I will accept the answer in 11 minutes. SO said I have to wait until that time.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a package, have you tried placing an `__init__.py` file? This would make sure that files from your subdirectories can be found. While you would have to change a little bit of code (especially in your import statements), this seems like it should be the way to go.